# Cancelling SplitView Close Event without Stopping Mouse Events

Tags: c#, xaml, winui-3, pane, splitview

I'm working on a WinUI 3 app, and I'd like to have my `SplitView.Pane` permanently open. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40890138/11968910) StackOverflow answer to try and solve the problem, however doing

```cs
private void SplitView_PaneClosing(SplitView sender, SplitViewPaneClosingEventArgs args)
{
    args.Cancel = true;
}
```

will stop all mouse events to children elements of the `SplitView`.

My question is whether there is a different way to keep the `SplitView` from closing its pane, or maybe another component to give me the same look as the `SplitView` without the pane being able to be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides setting `IsPaneOpen` to `True`, try setting `DisplayMode` to `Inline`.

```xml
<SplitView
    DisplayMode="Inline"
    IsPaneOpen="True">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <TextBlock Text="Pane" />
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <TextBlock Text="Content" />
</SplitView>
```

Comment: I was trying to, you answered too quickly, and StackOverflow wasn't letting me accept an answer yet!

Comment: Didn't know that StackOverflow doesn't let you accept answers too soon. Good to know. Thanks!